# How to iterate over several files in bash

Tags: bash

I have several files to compare. con and ref files contain list of paths to .txt files that should be compared,and the output should contain the variable name of con_vs_ref_1.txt.

con:

```
/home/POP_xpclr/A.txt
/home/POP_xpclr/B.txt
```

ref:

```
/home/POP_xpclr/C.txt
/home/POP_xpclr/D.txt
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

XPCLR="/home/Tools/XPCLR/bin/XPCLR"
CON="/home/POP_xpclr/con"
REF="/home/POP_xpclr/ref"
MAPS="/home/POP_xpclr/1"
OUTDIR="/home/POP_xpclr/Results"

$XPCLR -xpclr $CON $REF $MAPS $OUTDIR -w1 0.5 200 1000000 $MAPS -p1 0.95
```

Comment: What should happen with `A.txt` and `C.txt`, for example? Is the `XPCLR` command related to the problem? Can you "unfold" the loop and show for the limited set of  `A.txt` `C.txt` and `B.txt` and `D.txt` files what do you want to do?

Comment: the files contain the genotypes ( 1 0 1 0 1 1) and so on. I need to run xpclr to find the selection sweep regions...

Comment: ok, so you need to run `$XPCLR ... A.txt C.txt ... ` and `$XPCLR ... B.txt D.txt ... ` or like all possible combinations ex. `XPCLR ... A.txt D.txt ... ` too?

Comment: all possible combinations

Answer (score 1):

Comments in code.

```
# create an MCVE, ie. input files:
cat <<EOF >con
/home/POP_xpclr/A.txt
/home/POP_xpclr/B.txt
EOF

cat <<EOF >ref
/home/POP_xpclr/C.txt
/home/POP_xpclr/D.txt
ref

# join streams
paste <(
    # repeat ref file times con file has lines
    seq $(<con wc -l) |
    xargs -i cat ref
) <(
    # repeat each line from con file times ref file has lines
    # from https://askubuntu.com/questions/594554/repeat-each-line-in-a-text-n-times
    awk -v max=$(<ref wc -l) '{for (i = 0; i < max; i++) print $0}' con
) |
# ok, we have all combinations of lines
# now read them field by field and do whatever we want
while read -r file1 file2; do
     # run the compare function
     cmp "$file1" "$file2"
     # probably you want something along:
     "$XPCLR" -xpclr "$file1" "$file2" "$MAPS" "$OUTDIR" -w1 0.5 200 1000000 "$MAPS" -p1 0.95
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping over the file paths in your con and ref files is pretty easy in bash.

As for "the output should contain the variable name of con_vs_ref_1.txt", you haven't explained what you want very well, but I'll guess that you want the file created to be named according to that formula and inside the output directory. Something like `/home/POP_xpclr/Results/A_vs_C_1.txt`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

XPCLR="/home/Tools/XPCLR/bin/XPCLR"
CON="/home/POP_xpclr/con"
REF="/home/POP_xpclr/ref"
MAPS="/home/POP_xpclr/1"
OUTDIR="/home/POP_xpclr/Results"

for FILE1 in $(cat $CON)
do
    for FILE2 in $(cat $REF)
    do
        OUTFILE="$OUTDIR/$(basename ${FILE1%.txt})_vs_$(basename ${FILE2%.txt})_1.txt"
        $XPCLR -xpclr $FILE1 $FILE2 $MAPS $OUTFILE -w1 0.5 200 1000000 $MAPS -p1 0.95
    done
done
```

What's this doing...

- `$(cat $CON)` creates a subshell and runs `cat` to read your CON file, inserting the output (i.e. all the file paths) into the script at that point
- `for FILE1 in $(cat $CON)` creates a loop where all the values read from your CON file are iterated across and assigned to the FILE1 variable one at a time.
- `for FILE2 in $(cat $REF)` as above but with the REF file.
- `${FILE1%.txt}` inserts the value of FILE1 variable, with ".txt" extension removed from the end. This is called [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).
- `$(basename ${FILE1%.txt})` makes a subshell as before, `basename` strips the path of all the leading directories and returns just the filename, which we have already stripped of the ".txt" extension with the parameter expansion.
- `OUTFILE="$OUTDIR/$(basename ${FILE1%.txt})_vs_$(basename ${FILE2%.txt})_1.txt"` combines the above two dot points to create your new file path based on your formula.
- `do` and `done` are parts of the for loop construct that I hope are pretty self explanatory.

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and quote your variables (I know the OP didn't, but you should have fixed that).